# How to run scapy in cooked mode?

Tags: sockets, scapy, tcpdump, tunneling

I have a problem with capturing traffic.

My system is configured with two iterfaces - ethX and tunelX.
tunelX is a tunneling iterface.

The scapy and tcpdump are capture different count of packets.
The problem is the tcpdump runs, if the "any" iterface was set, in `cooked mode` but scapy don't.
`cooked mode` means that the `SOCK_DGRAM` will be created instead the `SOCK_RAW`. It is nessesary because some data in "tunneling packtes" in link-layer might be missing or contain not enoght data to determinate type of the packet.

When I ran strace with my **scapy sctipt** I saw this.

```
    927698 socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 768) = 4


    927689 recvfrom(3, "..some-data..."..., 65535, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(53), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "...some address...", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 105
    927689 recvfrom(3, "..some-data..."..., 32767, 0, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x86dd, if4, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(6)={1, 30d17e75727f}, [18]) = 246
    927689 recvfrom(3, "..some-data..."..., 32767, 0, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x86dd, if4, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(6)={1, 30d17e75727f}, [18]) = 86
    927689 recvfrom(3, "..some-data..."..., 32767, 0, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x86dd, if4, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(6)={1, 30d17e75727f}, [18]) = 86
    927689 recvfrom(3, "..some-data..."..., 32767, 0, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x86dd, if4, pkttype=PACKET_OUTGOING, addr(6)={1, 90e2ba55f6e8}, [18]) = 271
```

The only last packet was added into dump.

The question is:
Is my assumption right? :) How can I launch scapy in cooked mode? I couldn't find this in manual.

Thank you.